# IP Address control not binding WPF

Tags: wpf-controls

Hi I am using MVVM model and i followed 
http://firstbit.blogspot.com/2011/07/wpf-c-ipaddress-control.html
for IP control. 
But when i apply binding its not showing in the control.
Can any one help me.

```
cs:IPAddressControl  Text="{Binding ViewData.StartIP,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding}" x:Name="startIPControl" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" OverridesDefaultStyle="False">            
    </cs:IPAddressControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it the control doesn't implement a dependency property for Text property, so maybe this is the problem.

As far as I know you can only bind to a DependencyProperty on DependencyObject, have a look here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71348/Binding-on-a-Property-which-is-not-a-DependencyPro

I don't have time to send you an updated version of the control from the link you supplied, but I can tell about what I did with this one which also doesn't support binding:

https://wpfipaddress.codeplex.com/

Download its sources, in *IPAddressControl.xaml.cs* delete the *Properties* region, and replace with this one:

```
    #region Text dependency property

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency property field for TextProperty.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(IPAddressControl), new PropertyMetadata("0.0.0.0", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextPropertyChanged)));

    #region Text dependency property callbacks

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency property TextProperty changed callback.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d">Dependency object.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
    private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IPAddressControl o = d as IPAddressControl;

        // Do stuff here, then raise event for property changed.

        try
        {
            var value = e.NewValue as string;
            var splitValues = new string[4];
            if (value != null)
            {
                var splits = value.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                Array.Copy(splits, splitValues, splits.Length);
            }
            o.txtboxFirstPart.Text = splitValues[0];
            o.txtboxSecondPart.Text = splitValues[1];
            o.txtboxThridPart.Text = splitValues[2];
            o.txtboxFourthPart.Text = splitValues[3];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw new Exception("Error in IP control see inner exception!", ex);
        }

        o.RaiseTextChanged(e);
    }

    #endregion Text dependency property callbacks

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Text.
    /// </summary>
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(IPAddressControl.TextProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(IPAddressControl.TextProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when dependency property TextProperty changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler TextChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises TextChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
    protected virtual void RaiseTextChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.TextChanged != null)
            this.TextChanged(this, e);
    }

    #endregion Text dependency property
```